# Unable to find Mobile Development with .NET on visual studio installer version 17.9.0

Tags: visual-studio

I have uninstalled and installed visual studio installer and still can't find the Mobile Development with .NET workload. Please help!

uninstalled and installed visual studio 2022 installer but only can see Mobile Development with C++ and not .NET.I am using Visual Studio Community edition that should include the necessary components for Xamarin development out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Development with .NET workload is no longer supported on the newer versions of Visual Studio. Microsoft is no longer providing official updates, security patches, or technical support for this workload. Alternative option for building Android and iOS apps using .NET is using .NET MAUI (Multi-platform App UI).